# How to easily search for image names in Storyboards and Nibs on iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage, uistoryboard, nib, xcode-storyboard

I'm trying to clean out old images on a really big projects - with 5 storyboards and about 20 nibs. What is the best way to easily search the storyboards and nibs to make sure that they do not include the image files I'm trying to delete?

Answer (score 2):

In Project Navigator, right-click your storyboard file --> Open As Source Code. From there, search for the image file names.

Or do a full-text search on all your storyboard files, e.g. in Finder.

Comment: Thanks! The Finder solution worked well, since all my storyboards / nibs are in the same folder.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please feel free to accept the answer if you think it solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the version editor on a storyboard or nib you will see the backing XML and you can search your image names on that.